# php javascript jquery countdown?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a future date from a datetime field in a mysql database, it will only ever be no more than an hour or two ahead of the current time.

What I need is it to display a countdown in real time on the page, eg "2 minutes 5 secs", that obv counts down every second.

Would I need javascript for this? Or is jquery etc the new thing?
I dont know either, only a little php.

Answer (score 0):

As long as its realtime. You need [javascript](http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Javascript%20count%20down)

Your back-end PHP should query the db and insert the future time into the JS.

An example of a JS countdown :  GTA V's countdown here http://www.gtaforums.com/index.php?showforum=239

Comment: lol thanks, i was wondering when the gta trailer was released :P

Comment: @user1022585 I hope this helps. PS I deliberately put the link there, I'm super-hyped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already found the solution. But if someone is still looking for this solution, then this code might help.

```
Reverse timer from javascript:

var target_date = new Date('Aug 01 2014 20:47:00').getTime();
    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
    var countdown = document.getElementById('timeremaining');
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(function () {
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

        days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

        hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

        if(days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0 )
        {
           document.getElementById('timeremaining').innerHTML = '';
           clearInterval(countdownTimer);              
        }
        else
        {       
            if(days>0)
              {
                 days= days+'d,';
              } 
              else
              {
                 days='';
              }            
            countdown.innerHTML ='( ' + days + checkTime(hours) + ':'+ checkTime(minutes) + ':' + checkTime(seconds) +' remaining)';    
        }
    }, 1000);

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {i = '0' + i};  
        return i;
    }
```